# How to convert Object fields to JSON in apex?

Tags: apex, json

I want to Convert Object fields to JSON.How can I do?

fields :Name__c,furigana__c,Contact_Time__c

Contact_Time__c is the select list.

Convert to :

```
{
    "Name__c": "one",
    "furigana__c": "two",
    "Contact_Time__c ": [1,2,3]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is [`JSON.serialize()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_serialize):

```java
Account a = [SELECT Name, (SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts LIMIT 1) FROM Account LIMIT 1];
System.debug(JSON.serialize(a));
```

The output will be something like

```js
{
    "attributes": {
        "type": "Account",
        "url": "/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Account/001XXX"
    },
    "Name": "Stack Overflow",
    "Id": "001XXX",
    "Contacts": {
        "totalSize": 1,
        "done": true,
        "records": [
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Contact",
                    "url": "/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Contact/003YYY"
                },
                "AccountId": "001XXX",
                "Id": "003YYY",
                "FirstName": "John",
                "LastName": "Doe"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If `Contact_Time__c` is a multipicklist it will not be mapped to an array, but to a string with `;` as separator, so if the desired output must be the one showed in the question or if you cannot have extra properties in your JSON (like "attributes", "Id", etc..), you have to write your own apex class that map that structure:

```java
public class MeaningfulName {
    public String name;
    public String furigana;
    public List<Integer> contactTime;
    
    public MeaningfulName(YourSobjectType record) {
        name = record.Name__c;
        furigana = record.furigana__c;
        if (String.isNotBlank(record.Contact_Time__c)) {
            contactTime = new List<Integer>();
            for (String ct : record.Contact_Time__c.split(';')) {
                contactTime.add(Integer.valueOf(ct));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can create a new instance of that class and pass it to `JSON.serialize()`.

Since you need a property called "name__c" instead of "name", you could leverage [`String.replace()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_replace) to change it:

```java
String jsonString = JSON.serialize(classInstance).replace('"name":', '"name__c":');
System.debug(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I use the new apex class to set the json success.But I have another question.
The json is show {"name": "one"},But I want { "name__c": "one"}.name__c is the API name.
But I can not create like public String name__c .How can I do?

Comment: @Kyori I edited the answer to address this issue. By the way, could you please explain why the JSON's property must be the apiName? If the properties must match the apiName of the fields, they must be written with the right letter uppercase

Comment: I want use API name to work with external systems.
"they must be written with the right letter uppercase "
Understand!Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON.serialize(##YourObjectInstance##). This function will return String. For more information see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_serialize